# Apple maps view route duration without traffic

Tags: ios, maps

I am going to the airport tomorrow morning for a flight, the current time on maps shows as:

[image]

The average time to drive 25 miles considering this is a motorway route is around 30 minutes.

I want to view this route without traffic, as at 3/4 am I doubt there’ll be even any traffic.

How can I view this route without traffic?

I have tried:

1) Searching for traffic settings in the settings app (no results found)

2) Going to maps -> info and turning traffic off:

[image]

The route still shows as red and the same duration. After turning traffic off I have tried to restart the maps app etc.

I am on iOS 13.3.1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Google maps can do this, but it gives a range of values, from something less to something more than the rush hour time. I just tested to Gatwick, Apple & Google. Apple, 1:30 [now 7pm] Google [to arrive 4am] 1:05 to 1:30 I'm in N London, so that's 60 miles not 25, but there's no win, you just have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to schedule a drive or to view routes without traffic at the moment in Apple Maps. 
The Traffic button just displays the traffic on the map, it doesn't affect the routes.

The only thing you can do is use another app (like GMaps or Waze) and send feedback to Apple (Report an issue > Other Issue).